Why Does Breaking Entanglement Lead to Energy Release in Black Hole Firewalls?
I am currently exploring the concept of the black hole firewall, also referred to as the AMPS firewall. This idea suggests that the entanglement between in-falling and outgoing Hawking particles is disrupted, leading to the formation of a firewall. I am struggling to grasp why the breaking of this entanglement would result in the release of energy. Additionally, I am curious to learn more about any proposed mechanisms for how this process occurs.

See Section 3.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231
